# Errors while trying to install "wireless" with pip

Tags: terminal, macos, python

I have been trying to install "wireless" with pip but I keep getting errors.

```
sudo pip install wireless
The directory '/Users/student/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/student/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting wireless
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading wireless-0.3.2.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Comment: How did you install *pip*? Do you have a python3 install (e.g. with homebrew) besides the stock Python 2.7?

Comment: I ran the install with python 3 version of pip and it installed but the program I am trying to run still couldn't find the "wireless" module. from wireless import Wireless
ImportError: No module named wireless

Answer (score 1):

One proper way to install pip and [wireless](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wireless/0.3.2) in a dual Python environment (i.e. stock OS X Python 2.7 and brew's Python 3.6.1) is the get-pip.py method outlined here: [How do I use pip 3 with Python 3.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712519/how-do-i-use-pip-3-with-python-3-4).

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip2 #usually not necessary because pip2 already exists
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Then depending where you want to install *wireless* either

```
sudo pip2 install wireless #installs to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wireless
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install wireless #installs to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wireless
```

or both.